# Filter Django model on ForeignKeys that agree with each other

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to get records from a Model whose associated foreign keys (`related_name=answers`) collectively only have a single answer (`answer = models.CharField()`) among all that are related (in agreement).  I can get the models that have disagreeing answers using `Count(..., distinct=True)`, like so:

```
# get models with disagreeing answers
objs = (model.objects
        .annotate(ans_values=Count('answers__answer', distinct=True))
        .filter(ans_values__gt=1))
```

and I have a seemingly-working, but very hack solution to get answers in concord:

```
# objects with agreeing answers
key = my_answer
objs = (model.objects
        .filter(answers__isnull=False)
        .annotate(ans_max=Max('answers__answer'), 
                  ans_min=Min('answers__answer'))
        .filter(ans_max=key, ans_min=key))
```

Using `Max` and `Min` on a text field feels dirty, but I don't know The One Way™ to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you. It makes use of a [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object.

```
objs = model.objects.filter(
    answers__isnull=False,
    answers__answer=my_answer,
).exclude(
    ~Q(answers__answer=my_answer)
).distinct()
```

Comment: It looks like this is grabbing records where there are conflicts.